# How to fix this issue in drupal7 using windows

Tags: entities, bootstrapping

How to fix this issue ?

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/.../includes/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.inc'
>   (include_path='.:') in /var/www/.../includes/bootstrap.inc on line
>   3139